# How to perform select on a massive dataset of 10 billion+ rows

Tags: sql, select, bigdata

When a user registers, email must be unique, and the registration check must take 1 second at most.

How does Facebook / Google manage to perform a select on table with several billion rows, retrieving instant response.

Is it as simple as:

```
select email from users where email = "xxx@yyy.zzz" limit 1
```

Does having an index on `email` field and running this query on a super fast server do the trick?

Or is there more to it?

Comment: Partition the data across multiple nodes/servers. The partition is usually some key that would reasonable disperse a large dataset. All people that like broccoli on this partition. Then you can easily narrow down your search. Or even better...all people who's email starts with s,t,r on this server.

Comment: @ahojvole If i recall they used tricks to split it to multiple databases based on certain conditions. Also using technologies such as noSQL will improve speeds, and DB's works by subtraction of sets and binary trees which all contribute to speedy recall while maintaining scalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes. Though with that much data, I'm thinking you may want to look into things like sharding, etc. to make things even faster

When using SQL, indexing and uniqueness can be assured by utilizing primary keys. These primary keys are then used by the backend driving the database to ensure that there are no duplications in the table. Because the keys are used for indexing the rows in the table, this also means that lookup on even a large set of data is much quicker because of these indices. Set the primary key to be the email adress and you should be good to go in this case.

Even when using NoSQL databases like Mongo, Cassandra, etc. it is necessary to create indices on your data so that lookup is quick.